# Possible to display elements outside modal view in ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

currently I have an HTML file that have some content that I present in modalview upon click of a button. I wish to check if it is possible to display element in the HTML outside of the modal view.

I tried using css to style the element, but I am unable to move the element out of the modal-wrapper.

Please assist to advice.

I am not able to embed image into the post yet, so i provided a link.

[Modal View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVje7.jpg)

Comment: Why do you want to do it? Modal will go full screen in mobile so your element will disapear if it outside modal view

Comment: can you attache a image of what you want?

Comment: Hi Duannx, my modal view is not full size, it is 50% in height, I intend to put a logo outside the modal view.

Comment: Hi shashan,i will attached an image in awhile.

Comment: I have attached an image link showing the modal view in my original post content. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Duannx, any advice on this?

Comment: You mean the outside element is finger print icon? How do you create this modal and make it not full size?

Comment: I create a class to style the modal-wrapper and add the style to the function that open the modal view.

Comment: Ya. So you should make your modal full size again. And in your modal, create a backdrop handler click to dissmiss. Format your content to not fullsize. And now you can easy make your element outside your content with css. I think it is easier way

Comment: Hi @Duannx, thanks for your advice, but if i make the modal view full size and create a backdrop, it will not show the page before this modal view.

My desire outcome will be able to show some part of previous page as backdrop and display the desired modal view.

Comment: You can use `background: transparent` style for your modal to do it

Comment: oh, actually i found out that i can set the opacity for the background and then create a div to simulate the modal-wrapper. Thanks for your advice, i will try it out and see if it work.

Comment: Hmm, seem like it is not working, when i set the opacity as 0.5, i can create the backdrop that show previous page content. But in my html file, i create a div, but the div also being applied the opacity.

Comment: You should set `background: transparent` for your modal `ion-content` and `scroll-content`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By referring to the [making modals 50% of size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606619/ionic-2-modal-make-50-of-the-width) and [round icon css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33706736/circle-over-a-rectangle-using-css/33706768). I have build a sample below with your requirements. [You can find the working version here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-modal-with-top-circle)

Hope it helps and let me know if you have any issues.

[image: Expected Modal]

Modal.html

```
<ion-content padding class="main-view">
  <div class="overlay" (click)="dismiss()"></div>
  <div class="modal_content">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="modal-content">
  <h2>Welcome to Ionic!</h2>
  <p>
    This starter project comes with simple tabs-based layout for apps
    that are going to primarily use a Tabbed UI.
  </p>
  <p>
    Take a look at the <code>pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs,
    update any existing page or create new pages.
  </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

Modal.scss

```
modal-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media not all and (min-height: 600px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  ion-modal ion-backdrop {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-height: 0px) and (min-width: 0px) {
  .modal-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.main-view{
    background: transparent;
  }
  .overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: .5;
    background-color: #333;
  }
  .modal_content {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: calc(50% - (50%/2));
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #333;
    background: #e8e8e8;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(51, 51, 51, .35);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    //overflow: hidden;
  }

  .circle{
  position:absolute;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:3px solid white;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-55px;
  top: -40px;
  background: #d33;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.modal-content{
  padding-top: 5rem;
}
```

Comment: Hi Raj,

Thanks for your help. I tweak abit and it is working now.

Comment: Glad it helped :)